# Symfony Delete an user with Foreign Key

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem that i can't resolve. That's why i'm coming here.

On my website, an user can upload pictures and videos. When the user try to delete his account, he got a 500 error :

*"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"*

If i understood, i have to use "joinColumn" "onCascade" and "onDelete" (I want to **keep** the user's pictures and videos)

My User entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Cette adresse email est déjà utilisée.")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVerified = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Picture::class, mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $pictures;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Video::class, mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $videos;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Picture::class, mappedBy="fav")
     */
    private $favoris;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Video::class, mappedBy="fav")
     */
    private $fav;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pictures = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->videos = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->favoris = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->fav = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Picture[]
     */
    public function getPictures(): Collection
    {
        return $this->pictures;
    }

    public function addPicture(Picture $picture): self
    {
        if (!$this->pictures->contains($picture)) {
            $this->pictures[] = $picture;
            $picture->setAuthor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePicture(Picture $picture): self
    {
        if ($this->pictures->removeElement($picture)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($picture->getAuthor() === $this) {
                $picture->setAuthor(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Video[]
     */
    public function getVideos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->videos;
    }

    public function addVideo(Video $video): self
    {
        if (!$this->videos->contains($video)) {
            $this->videos[] = $video;
            $video->setAuthor($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeVideo(Video $video): self
    {
        if ($this->videos->removeElement($video)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($video->getAuthor() === $this) {
                $video->setAuthor(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Picture[]
     */
    public function getFavoris(): Collection
    {
        return $this->favoris;
    }

    public function addFavori(Picture $favori): self
    {
        if (!$this->favoris->contains($favori)) {
            $this->favoris[] = $favori;
            $favori->addFav($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFavori(Picture $favori): self
    {
        if ($this->favoris->removeElement($favori)) {
            $favori->removeFav($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Video[]
     */
    public function getFav(): Collection
    {
        return $this->fav;
    }

    public function addFav(Video $fav): self
    {
        if (!$this->fav->contains($fav)) {
            $this->fav[] = $fav;
            $fav->addFav($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFav(Video $fav): self
    {
        if ($this->fav->removeElement($fav)) {
            $fav->removeFav($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Picture entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PictureRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PictureRepository::class)
 */
class Picture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     */
    private $slug;

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $publication_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="pictures")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="favoris")
     */
    private $fav;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fav = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublicationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publication_date;
    }

    public function setPublicationDate(\DateTimeInterface $publication_date): self
    {
        $this->publication_date = $publication_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?User $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?string
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(string $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getFav(): Collection
    {
        return $this->fav;
    }

    public function addFav(User $fav): self
    {
        if (!$this->fav->contains($fav)) {
            $this->fav[] = $fav;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFav(User $fav): self
    {
        $this->fav->removeElement($fav);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Video entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\VideoRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VideoRepository::class)
 */
class Video
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $publication_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="videos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $vid;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="fav")
     */
    private $fav;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fav = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublicationDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publication_date;
    }

    public function setPublicationDate(\DateTimeInterface $publication_date): self
    {
        $this->publication_date = $publication_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?User
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?User $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?string
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(string $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->vid;
    }

    public function setVid(string $vid): self
    {
        $this->vid = $vid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getFav(): Collection
    {
        return $this->fav;
    }

    public function addFav(User $fav): self
    {
        if (!$this->fav->contains($fav)) {
            $this->fav[] = $fav;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFav(User $fav): self
    {
        $this->fav->removeElement($fav);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"If i understood, i have to use "joinColumn" "onCascade" and "onDelete"..."_ - have you actually tried any of these settings? If you have, can you please share how you've configured them and what happened in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to - when deleting a user - delete all his pictures and videos as well, you can just add cascade delete to the associations:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Picture::class, mappedBy="author", cascade={"delete"})
     */
    private $pictures;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Video::class, mappedBy="author", cascade={"delete"})
     */
    private $videos;
```

---

If you instead want to keep them and just remove the associoation to the user, add `ON DELETE SET NULL` to your `author_id` foreign keys in picture and video tables:

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="videos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $author;
```

Then you have to assume in your code that `$this->author` can be null.

Comment: With the second method it works but the pictures and videos are deleted too. I want to keep them.

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be `onDelete="SET NULL"`, I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: It works with onDelete ="SET NULL". Thank You very much !